# Closure of intersections of equivalence relations

Tags: general-topology

Given a $T_0$ space $X$ and an equivalence relation $\rho$ on the set of its point, denote by $\overline{\rho}$ the smallest equivalence relation that contains $\rho$ and that is a closed subset of $A\times A$ (with the product topology). Suppose now $A$ and $A'$ are $T_0$. Suppose $R$ is an equivalence relation on $A$ and $R'$ is an equivalence relation on $A'$ which is already closed in $A'\times A'$. Can I say that  the relation
$$\overline{\{(a,b,x,y)\mid (a,b)\in R\}}\cap \{(a,b,x,y)\mid (x,y)\in R'\}$$
is the smallest equivalence relation that contains $\{(a,b,x,y)\mid (a,b)\in R\}\cap \{(a,b,x,y)\mid (x,y)\in R'\}$ and that is closed in $A\times A \times A'\times A'$ (with the product topology)?

I know that in general closures do not behave well with intersections so I expect a negative answer,  but I couldn't find a counterexample.